# "Name of God" trap from Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade

Tags: indiana-jones, the-last-crusade

Is there a sketch/map of the "name of God" trap from *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade* somewhere on the Internet? I can't find one.

Comment: It may not exist... This question should be featured because its asking rather specific information that can't be found anywhere else. That and it's Indiana Jones, and well who can pass that up?

Comment: The funny thing about the "name of God" trap is that the "J" that Indy steps on shouldn't even be there.  Jehovah begins with an "I" in Latin because the Latin alphabet doesn't *have* a "J".

Comment: @Channel72 Those Knights are pretty tricky.

Comment: @Channel72 IT'S A TRAP!

Comment: @Channel72 - The even funnier thing is that the name Jehovah wasn't used until 1278 - much later than the trap was built. Jehovah was obtained by adding the vowels of "Adonai" to the consonants of "YHWH"

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here is a screen capture from the movie. I got this from [Desert-Sky.net](http://caps.desert-sky.net/lastcrusade.htm) "zip file 5" file: 921. This was the most complete screen shot I could find, and I don't own the movie to determine more.

This looks very different from what was portrayed in the comic strip on a different answer. For one thing the letters are not in square boxes in rows, but follow more irregular shapes.

[image: puzzle trap]

Answer (score 21):

Here are the panels from the comic adaptation. I don't know how accurate the comic was to the film, however:
[image]

http://www.imagebam.com/image/b680ab66606103

Comment: Is it me or does it look like a computer keyboard? :-) Ok, not a QWERTY-type one.

Answer (score 17):

I have taken a few screenshots from this video in 4K, which I have posted at the bottom of this answer. As far as I know, the only way to get anything better would be to actually own the movie to extract images directly from the video.

Since I have too much free time, I also went through the trouble of trying to draw what I could make out on Paint, although it pains me to admit that the dimensions are most likely wrong. Some tiles are empty, because some of them didn't have anything written, and some others because I couldn't make out what was written:

[image: A poor reproduction of the "Name of God" trap from the third Indiana Jones movie. The drawing is in top view and was made with Paint or equivalent, depicting the lettered tiles with approximate shapes and dimensions as they can be seen from within the movie.]

As a bonus, here's the path Indy took in the movie to reach the other end, numbered in blue from 1 to 6:

[image: Same drawing as above, but this time the letters I, E, H, O, V, A on which Indy stepped in the movie numbered from 1 to 6 to depict the path he took to reach the other side.]

Appendix with the various shots of the lettered tiles:

[image: A shot of the lettered tiles as Indy arrives in the room, after removing the spider web.]

[image: Similar to above, but the camera got closer, allowing to recognise some tiles with more ease.]

[image: Indy is looking at the first letter, the I, before proceeding with solving the trap. Notice how the tile on the left has no marking at all.]

[image: Indy is standing on the E tile, about to jump towards the H tile. A few lettered tiles are around it.]

[image: A close up on the O tile before Indy jumps on it. Once again, we can see some of the neighbouring lettered tiles.]

[image: Indy is stepping on the V tile and is about to jump towards the A tile.]

(Notice how the *P* tile, which was damaged when he jumped on the *O* tile, is no longer damaged)

[image: Indy standing on the A tile, which means he was able to reach the other side safely.]

Comment: Believe it or not, that Paint drawing took me 2 hours, and the blurry letters of some tiles didn't help. I have no idea why I felt the need to draw it on Paint though.

Comment: If you find the 'Making Of' on YouTube, you can see Spielberg moving the letters around to make the jumps harder for Indy

Comment: @Valorum _[surprised Pikachu face]_ Now I want to see it

Comment: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jNLUB_9XhAo 22 minutes in

Comment: I made a rollback to my own answer, because I realised I made a mistake in my latest drawing of the puzzle (I transformed an R into a K when it was indeed an R, and the H was indeed a K).

Comment: Self-reminder: the _H_ on the left below the _B_ actually is a _K_

Comment: Okay, I think I'm done fixing my mistakes over and over again

Comment: If there's one thing this site has taught me is that you're ***never*** done fixing your mistakes. One innocent comment can be enough to send you right back down that rabbit-hole

Answer (score 4):

I have [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0811809722) but unfortunately nothing about the "name of god" trap. You can anyway find quite a lot of pictures from props (mainly Henry Jones Sr. Grail Diary pages) coming from this book and a lot of others on [this (excellent) page](http://zenseeker.net/GrailDiary/OfficialGrailDiaryPages.htm).  Quite an amount of great pictures.
But as Henry Sr. didn't see the trap before, he had no drawing on it in his diary.

On all the pages I've seen here and there on the Internet, we can see a lot the Leap of Faith [special effect](http://www.theraider.net/films/crusade/gallery/makingof/mo_60.jpg) making of but alas nothing about the Name of God trap other than the picture already provided by Jeffrywith1e.